# 500 Error when inserting image into timeline using glassware starter project

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

Without modifying anything from the google-provided online mirror-api demo (https://glass-python-starter-demo.appspot.com/) , I get an error (when using the "Insert a picture" button"

The error:

"500 Internal Server Error

The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation."

I get a similar behavior (503 error) when performing the same procedure on a copy of the example project that is running on my computer (localhost).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any logs from the server which give the error the server encountered would probably help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have resolved itself without doing anything on my end.